# Extract Text from Varied HTML using Python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, lxml

Let's say you have a varied HTML block like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <a href="example.com">Blue</a>
  </div>
  Black
  </br>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <a href="example.com">Yellow</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <a href="example.com">Pink</a>
  </div>
  Orange
  </br>
</div>
```

What would your approach be, using python, to extract the colours from this HTML block?

Comment: Why mark as negative without comment?

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter (not me) thinks that you should explain what the problem is and what your own approach is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.text` to get all the colors from your sample html.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <a href="example.com">Blue</a>
  </div>
  Black
  </br>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <a href="example.com">Yellow</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <a href="example.com">Pink</a>
  </div>
  Orange
  </br>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.text.strip().replace(" ", ""))
```

**Output:**

```
Blue

Black


Yellow


Pink

Orange
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract a tag in html with regex, you might want to try this:

```
<(\w+)[\s\w\d=\-+\.]*>(.*)</\1\s*>
```

And then use group 2 to find everything inside of that tag. You could also change the start of the regex to:

```
<(a) (etc...)
```

And that will only match a tags.